# How Spark ensures data consistency if a node/partition fails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark

We have an ETL job running on spark which reads data from SQL Server. Then some transformations are performed on the dataframe by appying mappartition and a new dataframe with different schema is created. Some further transformations are done and finally the result dataframe is to be written back into SQL Server.

My question is suppose while inserting data in SQL Server in say 8 partitions, one of the spark node goes down, how will the spark ensure data integrity? The other partitions would have inserted data in database and at point of failure, data is inconsistent in database.

Will spark only re-create the failed partition by applying all the transformations?

In case the it fails again, what will be the state of other partitions' data in database?

Comment: I believe Spark is not ACID compliant unless you are using Delta Lake in Azure so it would not ensure consistency by design.  This is something left to the developer to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer.

> - If you have not check-pointed,
>
>   - then as you are not reading from a source that can track files initially used - in case of re-compute from source - e.g. Hive tables,
>
>     - recompute would occur and the results may differ for subsequent node failure recovery - unless that source is static.
> - With a .cache and/or checkpoint that can still be read somewhere else,
>
>   - my understanding is you would get the same result.
>
> Hard to test imho.

Extra Points

> The caching AFTER ALL transformations applied is not a standard thing
> to do. It is expensive. Moreover, due to memory issues and even
> storage issues, Spark can evict a partition and go back to source, so
> the data could differ to *previous invocation of processing*. And, if
> you persist and that Nodes goes down prior to write, you have lost the
> cache. Same situation.

Comment: Yes, I am caching data after all transformations are applied.Also, please answer this, if say I am writing dataframe to sql server in 8 partitions and 1 partition fails while other are successful, how will data consistency in database be maintained?

Comment: added some aspects. Need to see big picture.